# How can I make composer load a branch dynamically?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using composer to organize my vendor libraries. One of these libraries is a private repository of general system classes.

The problem is that I want to have my code run out of the dev branch when it's on the dev environment, and automatically use the dev branch of my composer library. When the code is on staging, I want to use the staging branch and have composer switch to use the staging branch of the composer library. Same for production.

Is it possible for composer to pull the correct branch without having to manually switch to that branch or edit the composer.json file?

Edit: useful answer is the comments of accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is not designed to dynamically include code. In fact, it is designed to intentionally NOT change the code on it's own, but only with developer interaction (i.e. explicitly updating).

So if you manage to require one version in your dev branch, and then merge this to staging, if you move the `composer.lock` unaltered, it will fetch exactly the version of your dev branch situation - now in staging. Which is actually a good thing because you do want to test the real software, and the software used to develop is the software that should go to staging and then to production - nothing else that is dynamically bound.

I am experiencing quite the same problem with an old legacy module. It does contain configuration data, which should get rolled out differently to dev, staging and production, but I cannot use Composer for this.

Maybe if you can describe your use case a bit more, there might be a solution for you. But I hardly believe it will contain Composer.

Comment: This issue isn't about having different configurations on each environment. My code already takes care of that. It's about having different versions of the code on each environment. 

We usually have several environments where our mobile apps can build new features. When those are done, we merge into the staging branch and finally to live. Since the composer library often has related changes, we need to keep the branches the same.

It's not ideal, and I don't necessarily agree with the process, but it is what it is.

Comment: There is a magic value that allows to stay in sync between two libraries: `self.version`. I've seen it being used to sync all the single modules of Zend Framework 2. Once a new version gets released, every library gets tagged with that new version - changes do not matter. But even this will require you to use the Composer workflow: Nothing will update automatically, you have to do it manually. If you are about to release version 4.15 of the main module, you have to update the dependencies to 4.15.x manually. Using `self.version` allows to not change the version in composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

### [Require inline alias](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#require-inline-alias)

Branch aliases are great for aliasing main development lines. But in order to use them you need to have control over the source repository, and you need to commit changes to version control.

This is not really fun when you just want to try a bugfix of some library that is a dependency of your local project.

For this reason, you can alias packages in your `require` and `require-dev` fields. Let's say you found a bug in the `monolog/monolog` package. You cloned Monolog on GitHub and fixed the issue in a branch named `bugfix`. Now you want to install that version of monolog in your local project.

You are using `symfony/monolog-bundle` which requires `monolog/monolog` version `1.*`. So you need your `dev-bugfix` to match that constraint.

Just add this to your project's root `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/you/monolog"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix as 1.0.x-dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: The `composer.lock` file will exactly record which commit id was used, and restore this very version, and nothing else. Unless you manually force an update, or indirectly force updates every time you install because you delete/do not commit the lock file, this will not dynamically grab the most recent commit.